# How to filter Ajax response and append on top last response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to filter response based on ID which is coming from server and append over the last response.

Let me put the code and explain my question.

**my jquery**

```
baseURL = 'http://192.168.23.110';

if ($('body').is('#body__page1')) {

var pFilter;

// First Ajax on document load
$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + '/page1/',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(response.id, function() {
            total += parseInt(this, 10);
        });
        var pvalue = response.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (b.id - a.id);
        });

        pFilter = dvalue[1].time;

        $.each(pvalue, function(key, value) {
            $('#page1__view').append('<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>' + value.username + '</h3> </a> </li>');
        });

    },
    error: function(xhr, err) {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});

//Second Ajax on button click
$('#page1__refresh').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + '/page1/?filter=' + pFilter,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var total = 0;
            $.each(response.id, function() {
                total += parseInt(this, 10);
            });
            var dvalue = response.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (b.id - a.id);
            });
            $.each(dvalue, function(key, value) {
                $('#page1__view').append('<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>' + value.username + '</h3> </a> </li>');
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            console.log(xhr.readyState);
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
    });
});

}
```

**server response**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "alfa",
    "time": "2016-12-29T08:56:11.607610Z",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "bravo",
    "time": "2016-12-29T08:56:12.616765Z",
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "charlie",
    "time": "2016-12-29T08:56:13.596835Z",
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "username": "delta",
    "time": "2016-12-30T06:00:13.250253Z",
}

]
```

As you can see in the **jquery code**. i have TWO Ajax calls one is on Document ready and another one is on button click.

The first ajax retrives successfully from server and store the time of last value in a variable ***pFilter*** and data populates in UL as

```
<ul id="page1__view">
<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>alfa</h3> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>bravo</h3> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>charlie</h3> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>delta</h3> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Now on second ajax whenever a user clicks on a button, ***pFilter*** variable from first call is appened in the second ajax call url and it retrives information.

For example if i take timestamp of charlie and appened in the url, it looks like this

```
http://192.168.23.110/?filter=2016-12-29T08:56:13.596835Z
```

and it will show response from Charlie as JSON which means i will get reposne as Charlie and Delta.

now what i am trying to achieve here is based on the timestamp i want to retrive new users (if registered any in this time) when user clicks refresh.

say for example, after the first ajax, there is two users added namely *Echo* and *foxtrot*.. Now when user clicks on refresh it should grab that users from server.

Cause of the Timestamp it retrives new users and the last user which i used his timestamp..

Basically what i am trying to do is, it should grab users after the specified time stamp based on the id. and prepand it to old list.

Comment: Please correct this fiddle as I can clearly see that something is wrong with the response (it has no direct id property) and `dvalue` is undefined in the first ajax call. I have mocked the ajax request for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gm7amtjz/

Comment: @latosinski: thank for the fiddle. I have updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/emjimadhu/4ncqL0n0/2/ now on the second ajax im recieving like that data cause i am including the last user time while querying to server. so it will gimme result from that timestamp.. now what i want is i dont want to include the first one but include everything else from the response. and 2) as you can see, that when i click on refresh the new datas goes to bottom of list.. i want it on top of exsisting response..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to store the initial data somewhere. I'd suggest inside your list as data attribute.

```
$('#page1__view').data('users', pvalue);
```

Now on every subsequent call just make a simple diff extracting unique users and append them all to your list:

```
var oldUsers = $('#page1__view').data('users');
var users = [...oldUsers, ...response]; //merge two arrays
var newUsers = getUnique(users, 'id');

var pvalue = newUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b.id - a.id);
});

// here we are replacing old list with the new one
$('#page1__view').empty();

$.each(pvalue, function(key, value) {
  $('#page1__view').append('<li> <a href="#!"> <h3>' + value.username + '</h3> </a> </li>');
});

$('#page1__view').data('users', pvalue);
```

Of course you can add some if statement to check if anything has changed so you don't mess with the DOM unnecessarily.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4ncqL0n0/6/) and [DIFF](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=frzt8)

Correct me if I've misunderstood you and we'll try to find some other solution.